# Tangent space of lie subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, tangent-spaces

If $H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$ (and $H$ not necessarily a submanifold  of $G$), would that still mean that $T_{e}H$ is a subspace of $T_{e}G$? My lecture notes define a Lie subgroup as just a subgroup that is a manifold, without any requirement that the smooth structure on $H$ is compatible with the smooth structure on $G$.

Comment: When you say "submanifold" do you mean embedded submanifold?  A Lie subgroup is always an immersed submanifold.

Comment: No, with submanifold I mean that it has taken over the smooth an topological structure of the ambient spaces.

Comment: That sounds like the same thing as an embedded submanifold, though I don't know what exact definition you have in mind.  What would be an example of a Lie subgroup you wouldn't call a submanifold?

Comment: Any subgroup that is a manifold, such that the smooth structure is not compatible with the smooth structure of G. Similar to how a subset of a topological space can be a topological space by defining some topology, while it doesn't have the subspace topology.

Comment: That is not what "Lie subgroup" normally means.

Comment: According to our lecture notes it is

Comment: I thought a Lie subgroup is a subset of $G$ such that the inclusion $H\to G$ is an injective immersion and group homomorphism and then $T_eH$ is considered a vector subspace of $T_eG$ as the image of $d_e i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard definition of a Lie subgroup of a Lie group $G$ is a subset $H\subseteq G$ equipped with a Lie group structure such that the inclusion map $i:H\to G$ is an immersion and a group homomorphism.  In particular, since $i$ is an immersion, it induces an injection $di_e:T_eH\to T_eG$ and so $T_eH$ can naturally be considered as a subspace of $T_eG$.

If you don't require the inclusion map to be an immersion, then all sorts of horrible things can happen.  For instance, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are isomorphic as abstract groups, so you could take $G=\mathbb{R}$ with its usual manifold structure and $H=\mathbb{R}$ with a manifold structure pulled back along a group isomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then $T_eH$ has larger dimension that $T_eG$, so it certainly cannot be considered as a subspace in any way.